# How to edit validation on Models generated by EF from a database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a database with a table users. I generate the EF .edmx from the database and I can then access the users via:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var obj = context.Users.ToList();
        return View(obj);
    }
```

Which is fine my problem is that when I do the edit:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    {
        var obj = context.Users.Where(c => c.UserId == id).SingleOrDefault();
        return View(obj);
    }
```

I have no idea how to access the User model to add validation message? I was hoping to see something like:

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
{
```

But I don't and I'm novice and don't really understand how to access / edit this model when generate from a database. Any advice tutorials would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see if u were using code first u could have used what user MISHA has suggested, u r using database first (as u are generating edmx from DB). In this case for mvc-validation to hook  automatically- you have provide model's metadata.

You can create a metadata as below

```
    namespace Your_Models_NameSpace
    {
        [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
        public partial class User
        {        
            public class UserMetaData
            {
                [DisplayName("User Name")]
                [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid username")]
                public object UserName { get; set; }
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: I seem to be having trouble with[Remote("UserNameExists", "Account", "Username is already taken.")] now. Blocks the entry but no message is displayed?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is, in the same namespace as your model, create a partial class with metadata like so:

```
   [MetadataType(typeof(IPConfigMetadata))]
    public partial class IPConfig
    {
        internal sealed class IPConfigMetadata
        {
            private IPConfigMetadata() { }

            [RegularExpression(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid IP Address")]
            public string CommanderIP { get; set; }

            [Range(1024, 65535)]
            public int IPPort { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) post.

You could do something like:

```
public class User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
{
```

Then in your action you would do:

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             // Save user
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```